# mockImplementation function signature

Tags: typescript, firebase, jestjs

I am trying to mock the result of `sendToDevice` of Firebase library, but I am stuck with the return value of `MessagingDevicesResponse` (see HERE on the code bellow)

```js
import MessagingDevicesResponse = admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse;

const fnMock = (registrationToken, payload) => Promise.resolve<MessagingDevicesResponse>(/* HERE */)

jest.spyOn(admin.messaging(), 'sendToDevice').mockImplementation(fnMock)
```

If I simple pass something like this

```js
Promise.resolve<MessagingDevicesResponse>({ canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0 })
```

I got the error:

```sh
Argument of type '{ canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MessagingDevicesResponse | PromiseLike<MessagingDevicesResponse>'.
  Type '{ canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MessagingDevicesResponse': failureCount, multicastId, results, successCountts(2345)
```

If I try:

```js
Promise.resolve<MessagingDevicesResponse>(new MessagingDevicesResponse())
```

I got:

```sh
'MessagingDevicesResponse' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` is indeed a `Promise<void>`, it doesn't resolve with any value. You need to resolve with a `MessagingDevicesResponse` or the code consuming the promise can't work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this issue I solved as you mentioned, now I got another issue

Comment: And again the compiler has told you exactly what the problem is - `{ canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0 }` is **not** a valid `MessagingDevicesResponse`.

Comment: No luck with `new MessagingDevicesResponse()`

Comment: Presumably it's a type or interface then, not an actual class, but you don't actually show the definition.

Comment: Yes. It is a interface. There's no implementation because this lib was written in JavaScript.

Comment: Then it's not clear why you expected `new MessagingDevicesResponse()` to work. JavaScript doesn't have types, TypeScript types are erased at compile time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's no way to I achive this?

Comment: You could provide an object that *does* have all of the relevant props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```js
const results: MessagingDeviceResult[] = []
const response = { results } as MessagingDevicesResponse
const returnValue = Promise.resolve<MessagingDevicesResponse>(response)
const spy = jest.spyOn(admin.messaging(), 'sendToDevice').mockReturnValue(returnValue)
```